# jQuery effects not working on Bootstrap modal close class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**What I am trying to do?**

I am trying to implement my own effect when modal is opened and when it's closed rather than using the Bootstrap fade class.

**What is the problem?**

I was able to add my effect when modal was opened, but I failed to do the same when modal was closed on the close class.

#### HTML:

```
<!-- Navigational Bar -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span ><i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i></span>
    </button>

    <div class="container" id="responsiveContainer">

        <!-- Title -->
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'index' %}"> abc </a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav">
                <li id="nav-form">
                    <form class="navbar-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="searchBox" class="form-control">
                            <button id="search" type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span>  <i class="fa fa-search"></i> </span></button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" id="authentication" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></i> Sign In/Up </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#" data-target=".signupModal" data-toggle="modal" id="signup"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Sign Up </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-target=".loginModal" data-toggle="modal" id="signin"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Sign In </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="nav">
                <li><a href="{% url 'articles' %}"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i> Article </a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Contact </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<!-- Login Modal -->

<div class="modal loginModal" dat-backdrop="false" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"> <i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-5x"></i></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputUserName"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Username </label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="&#xf040; Username" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome" id="inputUserName">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword"><i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i> Password</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="&#xf040; Password" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome" id="inputPassword">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="login"> Login </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// This works
$('#signin, #signup').click(function() {

        var $name = $(this).attr('data-target');
        $($name).fadeIn("Slow");
});

// This doesn't
$('.modal .close').click(function() {

        var $parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
        var $this = $parent.attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        $($this).fadeOut("Slow");
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to call `fadeOut('show')` on the loginModal?  If so then you could simply do `$(this).closest('.modal').fadeOut('show')`.  No need for all that parent parent split extra lookups mess.

Comment: @Taplar sorry i meant "Slow" not 'show' i forgot to edit it here.

Comment: @Taplar that does not work :(

Comment: @Taplar yes it doesn't work i just checked it again.

Comment: $('.modal .close').click(function() {
                        console.log($(this).closest('.modal').attr('class'));
 });     // it works

Comment: yeah as "modal loginModal in"

Comment: Mmm, you got me stumped then.  That would seem to say it's finding the right element, and if you did a fadeIn() on that guy, you should be able to do a fadeOut() to undo what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the fix, and here it is:

I removed the `data-dismiss` attribute in the HTML from my modal close button and altered the jQuery code like so:

```
$('#signin, #signup').click(function() {

    var $name = $(this).attr('data-target');
    $($name).fadeIn("Slow");
});

$('.modal .close').click(function() {

    var $this = "#" + $(this).parents("div.modal").attr('id');

    $($this).fadeOut("Slow");

    setTimeout(function(){
        $($this).modal('hide');
    }, 500);
});
```